# I can't select a row from a DataTable

Tags: javascript, html, datatable

I have a DataTable that is created dynamically according to the result of a SELECT, the first time it is created it does not give me any problem, but when I change the SELECT, still reloading the table, the data of it cannot be accessed

In the browser console appears this error message:
Uncaught TypeError: can't access property "name", informe is undefined
 file:///C:/Users/jordi.burgos/Downloads/ejemplo minimo/index.js:40
jQuery 8
 file:///C:/Users/jordi.burgos/Downloads/ejemplo minimo/index.js:36
jQuery 2

You can see this error in https://codepen.io/jordibonarea/pen/OJvNOZB

I have created a minimum code to be able to model the example:
index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Ejemplo mínimo</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- DataTables -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Este es el ejemplo mínimo para que de error el DataTable</h1>
    <select name="prueba_select" id="prueba_select">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
    <table id="table_prueba"></table>
    <div id="item_selected">    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#prueba_select').change(function (e) { 
        e.preventDefault();
        var $tabla_modal_informes = $('#table_prueba').DataTable({
            destroy: true,
            "data": [
                {
                    "name":       "Tiger Nixon",
                    "position":   "System Architect",
                    "salary":     "$3,120",
                    "start_date": "2011/04/25",
                    "office":     "Edinburgh",
                    "extn":       5421
                },
                {
                    "name": "Garrett Winters",
                    "position": "Director",
                    "salary": "5300",
                    "start_date": "2011/07/25",
                    "office": "Edinburgh",
                    "extn": "8422"
                },
                // ...
            ],
            "columns": [
                { "data": "name" },
                { "data": "position" },
                { "data": "office" },
                { "data": "extn" },
                { "data": "start_date" },
                { "data": "salary" }
            ]
        });
        //cuando hacemos click en sus filas
        $('#table_prueba').on('click','tr',function () {
            //$tabla_modal_informes.rows().deselect();
            // Ontiene datos de la fila seleccionada
            let informe = $tabla_modal_informes.row(this).data();
            $('#item_selected').html('<h3>' + informe.name +'</h3>');
        });
    });
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just changed the scope where `$table_modal_informes` is defined putting its declaration outside of the ready event handler so that you'll have only one reference to one DataTable object at any given time.

As you can see in the snippet, now you are free to select rows from the table any time also after the selected data table was changed from the corresponding dropdown:

```js
var $tabla_modal_informes;

$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#prueba_select').change(function (e) { 
        
        e.preventDefault();
         $tabla_modal_informes = $('#table_prueba').DataTable({
            destroy: true,
            "data": [
                {
                    "name":       "Tiger Nixon",
                    "position":   "System Architect",
                    "salary":     "$3,120",
                    "start_date": "2011/04/25",
                    "office":     "Edinburgh",
                    "extn":       5421
                },
                {
                    "name": "Garrett Winters",
                    "position": "Director",
                    "salary": "5300",
                    "start_date": "2011/07/25",
                    "office": "Edinburgh",
                    "extn": "8422"
                },
                // ...
            ],
            "columns": [
                { "data": "name" },
                { "data": "position" },
                { "data": "office" },
                { "data": "extn" },
                { "data": "start_date" },
                { "data": "salary" }
            ]
        });
        //cuando hacemos click en sus filas
        $('#table_prueba').on('click','tr',function (event) {
            //$tabla_modal_informes.rows().deselect();
            // Ontiene datos de la fila seleccionada            
            let informe = $tabla_modal_informes.row(this).data();
            $('#item_selected').html('<h3>' + informe.name +'</h3>');
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Ejemplo mínimo</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- DataTables -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Este es el ejemplo mínimo para que de error el DataTable</h1>
    <select name="prueba_select" id="prueba_select">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
    <table id="table_prueba"></table>
    <div id="item_selected">    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer now I will try in the production code and I have another question... How did you create the snippet? Thanks other time.

Comment: in the rich text editor where you type your question/answer, there's a toolbar with some buttons like: bold, italic, hyperlink, blockquote, code sample, image ... and Javascript/HTML/CSS snippet. That's the button to add a code snippet like the one where I pasted your code and just made a veeeery slight edit.